# Setting scale to a negative number with BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Does it ever make sense to set the scale to a negative number like this?

```
BigDecimal result;
    .
    .
    .
result = result.setScale(-1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

What happens if you do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to set the scale to a negative number in certain situations.  That just means that the number is rounded to the nearest `10` to the `-scale` number, or just `10` in this case.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(1094);
bd = bd.setScale(-1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(bd);
System.out.println(bd.doubleValue());
```

Prints

```
1.09E+3
1090.0
```

The `1.09E+3` is equivalent to the `double` value `1090.0`.

This is useful when the scientific measurement for a quantity has less significant digits than the total number of digits necessary to represent the number normally.  The precision of such a number is less than the size of the number.

If Earth's distance from the Sun is given as 92,960,000 miles, and if this value is only 5 significant digits, then that is equivalent to

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(92960000.0);
bd = bd.setScale(-3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);// 3 insignificant/imprecise "0" digits
System.out.println(bd);
```

Which prints

```
9.2960E+7
```

The number is rounded to the nearest 1,000.

Comment: Fwiw, 1.09e+2 equals 109, not 1090.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks; I've edited my answer to correct that value and for another minor clarification.