# What does negative scale mean with respect to BigDecimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), a negative scale means that:

> the unscaled value of the number is multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale. The value of the number represented by the BigDecimal is therefore (unscaledValue × 10-scale)

But suppose I have the following:

```
BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("754.000");
```

This has a scale of 3 because there are three decimals to the right of the decimal point. Then I change the scale as follows:

```
BigDecimal b2 = b1.scaleByPowerOfTen(4);
```

Now, the scale is negative: 3-4 = -1 and `b2` has the unscaled value of 7540000. Applying the Javadoc, negative scale definition:

- the unscaled value of the number is multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale = 7540000 X 10^-(-1) = 75400000.

But this is wrong as the value is actually 7540000. What is wrong with my understanding? If I print the value to the console:

```
System.out.println(b2);
```

I get 7.54000E+6. Why does it print the number in scientific notation? What rule is it using here for printing? If negative scale, is the value always printed in scientific notation?

**Update (as requested to show why another post doesn't answer my questions)**

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590590/setting-scale-to-a-negative-number-with-bigdecimal) to this post tells me the use of negative scale. Specifically, it indicates its usefulness in rounding and scientific measurement. It does not explain what negative scale means, what is wrong with the way I'm applying the Javadoc to my example, and why it prints in scientific notation.

Comment: The docs say "`scaleByPowerOfTen(int n)`: Returns a BigDecimal whose numerical value is equal to (this * 10^n).". So this is expected behaviour. The method doesn't set the scale to this value, but rather scales the number by this amount.

Comment: Agree; the doc states "Returns a BigDecimal whose numerical value is equal to(this * 10^n)." And then it states "The scale of the result is (this.scale() - n)." So, in my example, the value becomes 7540000 and the scale becomes 3-4=-1. I'm trying then to understand what -1 (or more generally what negative) scale means though. Applying the Javadoc definition, leads to my questions in the OP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting scale to a negative number with BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590590/setting-scale-to-a-negative-number-with-bigdecimal)

Comment: `new BigDecimal("754.000").scaleByPowerOfTen(4).unscaledValue()` is `754000`, rather than `7540000`. The scale is `-1`, so it has a value of `754000 * 10^1`, or `7540000`.

Comment: @Joe - Thanks for asking but I read that prior to posting. It tells me a use of negative scale (i.e. rounding) but doesn't answer my questions about what negative scale means. Your second comment does help answer. I was not expecting the unscaled value of `b2` to be 754000. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be **7540000** since that is equal to 754.000 x 10^4 and follows the JavaDoc of `scaleByPowerOfTen(int n)`: "Returns a BigDecimal whose numerical value is equal to(this * 10^n)."

Comment: I think my misunderstanding from the `scaleByPowerOfTen(int n)` Javadoc is that "numerical value" does not mean "unscaled value".

Comment: Negative scale can be used for scientific notation, e.g. `new BigDecimal("5.1E2").scale()` == -2

Comment: @Joe - I think you've answered my question by showing what the unscaled value is and me realizing "numeric value" in the Javadoc is not equal to "unscaled value". Also, according to the `BigDecimal` `toString` Javadoc: "Otherwise (that is, if the scale is negative, or the adjusted exponent is less than -6), the number will be converted to a character form using exponential notation". So this answers my questions about the rule of printing in scientific notation.

Comment: This reminds me of the [old joke](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/7nl70d/65000011_years_ago/) about the dinosaur bones being "65,000,011" years old, because the worker was told 65 million years, and it's been 11 years since he started working there.  He assumed a high degree of precision that we don't have. That is the difference between a scale of `0`, which would be printed `65000000`, implying we have it down to the year, vs. "around" 65 million years ago, unscaled value `65`, scale `-6`. It's printed in scientific notation, because 6.5*10^7 implies the smaller precision we do have.